# Spring Cloud Stream: Cannot connect to 2 rabbitmq clusters without allowOverride

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

I have a spring boot application (let's call it example-service) with the following configuration to connect to 2 different rabbitmq clusters.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: rabbitA
      binders:
        rabbitA:
          inheritEnvironment: false
          defaultCandidate: false
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                addresses: rabbitmq-a:5672
                username: user-a
                password: password-a
        rabbitB:
          inheritEnvironment: false
          defaultCandidate: false
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                addresses: rabbitmq-b:5672
                  username: user-b
                  password: password-b
      bindings:
        dataFromA:
          destination: exchange-1
            group: queue-1
          binder: rabbitA
        dataFromB:
          destination: exchange-2
            group: queue-2
          binder: rabbitB
```

That itself works fine, it connects to both clusters. The problem is that this service is deployed in an environment where there is a spring config server with the following files:

application.yml

```
spring.rabbitmq:
  addresses: rabbitmq-a:5672
  username: user-a
  password: password-a
```

Then that seems to override the configuration set for each binder, located under the "environment" property. So I needed to add this extra config.

example-service.yml

```
spring.cloud:
  config:
    overrideSystemProperties: false
    allowOverride: true
    overrideNone: false
```

Now the example-service connects to both rabbitmq clusters again. But I have observed certain side effects, mainly not being able to override other properties in the config server example-service.yml anymore, which is a real need for me. So I have discarded using allowOverride and its related properties.

**The question is...** is it possible to make it work without using allowOverride, while keeping the spring.rabbitmq.addresses/username/password in the remote config server application.yml?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? I just tested it with 3.0.6 and it works fine:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        rabbitA:
          type: rabbit
          inherit-environment: false
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                virtual-host: A
        rabbitB:
          type: rabbit
          inherit-environment: false
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                virtual-host: B
      bindings:
        input1:
          binder: rabbitA
          destination: input1
          group: foo
        input2:
          binder: rabbitB
          destination: input2
          group: bar
  rabbitmq:
    virtual-host: /
```

[image]

Probably not related, but your `group` indentation is wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's only an issue when using Config Server.

Comment: What happens if you move your binder configs to `example-service.yml` instead of as a local yml?

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks a lot for your comments It seems to be an issue with having the spring.rabbitmq.* properties coming from the config server. What I observed is that once they come as externalised config, These properties from config server override the binder.environment ones (even if you define the binder in the config server). Then the only way to preserve the binder.environment properties was using the spring.cloud.config.allowOverride property. I am using spring cloud stream 3.0.1. I found a workaround, though. I will post it later in the day.